# Trying to make the values of one column into the rows of a new table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a new table that uses the values in one row (the entire column) from an existing table and turn them into the columns.

I want it to work kind of like how `INSERT INTO … SELECT DISTINCT` works for filling a column, but making that result the new columns of a table.

Right now the values in the column that I want to make rows are:

> 001 - June 2018
>   002 - July 2018
>   003 - August 2018
>   …
>   013 - June 2019

However, I can't just hard-code them in since I want this to run as more months are added (July 2019, etc.)

I want to have a table that has columns with the same names as the rows because I am trying to compare performance each month from other variables, such as which user drove the most each month.

So far, from previous answers here, I tried creating a string that could be executed to create the table.

```
select @s:=concat('create table students_col (',group_concat(driving_month,' CHAR(100)' order by driving_month),')') from new_drivers;
prepare statement from @s;
execute statement;
deallocate prepare statement;
```

However, although there are no red underlines from MySQL Workbench, I get an error code for each statement besides selecting the concatenated statement.

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'June 2018 CHAR(100),July 2018 CHAR(100),August 2018 CHAR(100),' at line 1
>   Error Code: 1243. Unknown prepared statement handler (statement) given to EXECUTE
>   Error Code: 1243. Unknown prepared statement handler (statement) given to DEALLOCATE PREPARE

When I ran the query with `@s` on its own, everything worked fine and don't know where the error in my syntax is.

I'm open to any way of doing this better. I just want to be able to easily make tables where the months are automatically created as rows. Unfortunately, to keep things sorted with other information, I can't just extract the month and year from the string so I need the 001, 002... as well.

Comment: Column name `June 2018` cannot have spaces in unless you wrap the column name in backticks like `\`June 2018\``

Comment: (just realized that the driving months in the backticks excludes it as code on stack overflow but like this?) `group_concat(`driving_month`,' CHAR(100)' order by `driving_month`),')') from new_drivers;`

Comment: @ssskay You can escape backticks with backslash in comments: `group_concat('\`', driving_month, ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `driving_month` contains spaces, you need to put backticks around it to create the column name.

```
select @s:=concat('create table students_col (',group_concat('`', driving_month,'` CHAR(100)' order by driving_month),')') from new_drivers;
```